# jQuery UI preventing the attempted sort of a connected list based on an arbitrary condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have many connected sortable lists, but when a list meets certain conditions, I want the list to be able to still reorder and have itmes removed from it, but not able to have new items added to it.

Please tell me if my question is not clear. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/1/

Comment: Interesting question, although not quite clear to me.  So the `special` list in your example should not be able to grow larger than 4 items, right?

Comment: correct, but that was just my example condition

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `activate` `receive` and `deactivate` will do the trick. 
http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/7/

Answer (score 0):

Check my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/2/)

I added this below your console output:

```
$('#special').sortable({
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        $(ui.sender).sortable( "option", "placeholder", 'custom' );
    }
});
```

Once your condidtion is reached, this reverts any new list elements dragged to that list, so the list will not get bigger, but you can still remove elements and re-order elements yourself.  Adding the **empty** custom css to the placeholder will make the placeholder take up no space, so you can not see it when you drag onto the special container.

Comment: I am aware of the `cancel` option, however. I am wanting to prevent ANY add interaction, including the addition of the placeholder. Also, the goal is to also have a red overlay indicating that the sortable cannot be dropped in the list, but i only want it there while the user is dragging

Comment: I know how i am going to do the overlay, but I can't seem to keep the placeholder from being placed. I think I have a (ugly,messy) way of doing it if nothing else works...

Comment: @nathanjosiah if you noticed in this latest jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TdnZp/8/), after you meet that condition the place holder stops showing up.